PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file in react native. [React Native IOS privacy manifest]
I am using React Native version 0.73.4 and recently upgraded to 0.73.8. During the pod installation, a file named PrivacyInfo.pbxproj was created. I need to add the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file to my project.
How can I do this?
I am seeing this warning when I run pod install in the iOS folder:
Your app does not have a privacy manifest! A template has been generated containing Required Reasons API usage in the core React Native library. Please add the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file to your project and complete data use, tracking and any additional required reasons your app is using according to Apple's guidance: https://developer.apple.com/.../privacy_manifest_files. Then, you will need to manually add this file to your project in Xcode.
Image:

How can i Add PrivacyInfo.pbxproj in my react native IOS project?
I copied and pasted the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file into my main project in the ios/exampleProject folder. However, I still see the same warning whenever I run pod install.

These are the steps directly taken from the apple documentation

To add the privacy manifest to your app or third-party SDK in Xcode, follow these steps:

Choose File > New File.
Scroll down to the Resource section, and select App Privacy File type.
Click Next.
Check your app or third-party SDK’s target in the Targets list.
Click Create.

By default, the file is named PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy this is the required file name for bundled privacy manifests.

But if you work with Expo, they also have an implementation of it, take a look at the documentation as well
